# Find average score from event at specific meeting

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the average score from everyone that took part in a high jump event at a specific event (ex event01)

My tables are MEETING, EVENT, RANK and my broken code is below:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT M.MEETING_ID, M.MEETING_NAME, E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_NAME,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY R.RESULT) RN, (SELECT AVG(RESULT) FROM RANK WHERE E.EVENT_NAME = 'HIGH JUMP' AND M.MEETING_ID = 'MEET0002' ) AS HG

FROM MEETING M JOIN RANK R ON M.MEETING_ID = R.MEETING_ID
JOIN EVENT E ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID  


)

WHERE RN = 1
```

Expected outcome:

```
MEETING_ID    MEETING_NAME    EVENT_ID    EVENT_NAME    AVERAGESCORE
meet01        sports day      event01     high jump     10.6
```

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an aggregation query with filtering:

```
SELECT M.MEETING_ID, M.MEETING_NAME, E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_NAME,
       AVG(RESULT) AS HG
FROM MEETING M JOIN
     RANK R
     ON M.MEETING_ID = R.MEETING_ID JOIN
     EVENT E
     ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID  
WHERE E.EVENT_NAME = 'HIGH JUMP' AND M.MEETING_ID = 'MEET0002' 
GROUP BY M.MEETING_ID, M.MEETING_NAME, E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_NAME;
```

You need the `GROUP BY` to include the first four columns in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Why filter at `WHERE` clause when you can filter things at JOIN itself.

```
SELECT M.MEETING_ID, M.MEETING_NAME, E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_NAME,
   AVG(RESULT) over (partition by E.EVENT_ID) AS avg
FROM EVENT E
 JOIN RANK R   
 ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID AND E.EVENT_ID = '001' AND E.EVENT_NAME='HIGH JUMP' 
 JOIN  
  MEETING M 
 ON M.MEETING_ID = R.MEETING_ID;
```